# Enable breakline in blockCode with pandoc

Tags: pdf, pandoc, markdown

I'm kinda new with LaTeX so maybe what I'm asking is evident.

I want to use `pandoc` for translate `markdown` files in `pdf`. After many tries, I've manage to break blockcode when the line is too long. But I still got issue : if I've no space, they're no line return.

Here a sample of the `markdown` to format :

```markdown
sed -i 's|plugin=libnm-vpn-plugin-wireguard.so|plugin=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-vpn-plugin-wireguard.so|g' /usr/lib/NetworkManager/VPN/nm-wireguard-service.name
```

And here's the LaTeX code I've set so far :

```
\usepackage{fvextra}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines, breakanywhere, breakafter=\/, commandchars=\\\{\}}

%\let\oldHighlighting\Highlighting
%\renewcommand{\Highlighting}[1]{
%   \allowbreak{\oldHighlighting{#1}}
%}


\let\oldtexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
    \allowbreak{\oldtexttt{#1}}
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
```

And here is the result I've got. You can see two lines who don't break.
[image: The outputted pdf]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `breaknonspaceingroup` in your `DefineVerbatimEnvironment`.
This option was added to `fvextra` v1.5, so make sure you have the latest version installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the `fvextra` lib and add `breaknonspaceingroup` but it's still the same output. I keep searching...